# Target class [PageController] does not exist, in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have created an api in api.php, But in git bash I am getting the following issue :

[image]

My codes from api.php :

```
<?PHP

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
  return $request->user();
 });

 Route::post('summitRegistration',[PageController::class,'summitRegistration']);
```

my controller path is :

[image]

Comment: Add `use App\Http\Controllers\User\PageController;` in your api.php

Comment: thanks bro, it's working, another issue is : I am trying to submit form from a HTML file, but when this rout is getting hit, it's saying "site refused to connect"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller is under `User` namespace, so you should change the line

```
 Route::post('summitRegistration',[PageController::class,'summitRegistration']);
```

to

```
 Route::post('summitRegistration',[User\PageController::class,'summitRegistration']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::post('summitRegistration',[PageController::class,'summitRegistration']);
```

To

```
Route::post('summitRegistration',[\App\Http\Controllers\User\PageController::class,'summitRegistration'])->name('summitRegistration');
```